# is it possible that i deleted my files while trying to delete a symbolic link?

Tags: command-line, bash

I made a symbolic link that points to a 500gb ntfs drive, when i executed the second command it halted for 3 seconds so i terminated it, i have a lot of files on the drive im not sure if it deleted anything

> root@myhost:/home/myuser/Desktop# rm /media/d/ rm: cannot remove
>   ‘/media/d/’: Is a directory root@myhost:/home/myuser/Desktop# rm
>   /media/d/ -r ^C

Comment: What exact command did you use? Just `rm`? `rm -rf`? Or any other flag?

Comment: rm /media/d/ -r

Comment: See my answer. I'm afraid you've deleted a bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am indeed afraid you have deleted the contents of the drive.

`rm -r /media/d/` will recursively delete anything inside `/media/d/`, even if `/media/d` itself is a link. What you should have used is `rm -f /media/d`, which will only delete the link. THe `-f` flag is needed because it is a folder, not a file.

It probably has deleted quite a lot in those 3 seconds. It will, however, not delete directories itself. If this command would've finished it would have left you with an empty directory structure!

Comment: true, i have missing files in one directory. but how does it work? does it remove files randomly or it goes from one directory to another?

Comment: `rm -r dir` will _recursively_ delete the contents of `dir`. That is to say, it will loop through `dir`, delete files, see if there are folder, delete files in those, find folders in subfolders, delete files in those etc. I'm not sure of the exact order of things here.